# Hacer un Insert OLEDB con SQL a un archivo dbf con subconsultas condicionales

Tags: sql, subconsultas, oledb

Estoy tratando de hacer un insert a un archivo dbf usando el OLEDB desde una api cuando recibo un listado de objetos. EL inconveniente que tengo es que mi Insert debe llenar 2 campos con dos subconsultas. Una es aparentemente sencilla y creo no tiene inconveniente, la segunda es mas jodida porque hago un select filtrando sobre la tabla destino por numero de documento y fecha contra los valores que llegan de la lista de objetos, y alli tengo un condicional donde si el valor devuelto haciendole un modulo (%->para sql) si es PAR, entonces en el campo se inserta "E" y sino "S"
Codigo

```
      bool InsertarVFP(List<Resultados> lstResultados)
        {
     string strCadenaConexion = @"C:\DestinoDBF";
            DBHelperVFPDBF db = new DBHelperVFPDBF(strCadenaConexion);
            if (db.ProbarConexion())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entre");
                string query = "INSERT INTO relojj (id, numdoc, fecha, maquina, tipo, veces, sucursal, transf, forma, audito, newfld ) " +
                                "VALUES (@id,@numdoc,@fecha,@maquina,@sucursal," +
                                "IIF((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM relojj WHERE numdoc=@numdoc and fecha=@fecha)%2=0 , 'E', 'S')," +
                                "(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM relojj WHERE numdoc=@numdoc and fecha=@fecha)," +
                                "@sucursal,@transf,@forma,@audito,@newfld)";
                //parametros
                string maquina = "Reloj Rio Grande";
                string forma = "R";
                string audito = "Alta Automatica";
                string newfld = "";
                string id ="100000";
foreach (var resultado in lstResultados)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query))
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", id);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", resultado.Legajo);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?",resultado.Dia);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?",maquina);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?","0028");                                
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?",DateTime.Now);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?",forma);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?",audito);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?",newfld);


                            db.EjecutarQuery(command); // ejecuta el metodo de la clase DBHelperVFPDBF

                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.Error(e.Message);
                    } 
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Este seria mi metodo que se dipara en la api.
El error viene siendo este

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Error de sintaxis en la expresión de consulta 'IIF((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM relojj WHERE numdoc=@numdoc and fecha=@fecha)%2=0 , 'E', 'S')'.'

Dejo el metodo EjecutarQuery por las dudas pero ya esta probado el insert común.

```
     public bool EjecutarQuery(OleDbCommand Comando)
    {
        bool retorno = false;
        
        if (Comando.CommandText != "")
        {
            OleDbConnection conexion = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            try
            {
                conexion.Open();
                if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    Comando.Connection = conexion;
                    Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conexion.Close();
                    retorno = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log(Comando.CommandText);
                Log(ex.Message);
                Log(ex.Source);
                Log(ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conexion.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                { conexion.Close(); }
            }
        }
        
        return retorno;
    }
```

Tambien probe un WHEN CASE pero sin exito. Tambien aclaro que revise el tipo de dato del objeto y lo que envio y matchean.

Comment: a un archivo dbf... o sea, estas esperando que dbf entienda iif???

Comment: La verad es que lo que espero es que se inserte los datos como indique. Si tienes una solucion, sera bienvenida. Supongo que me estas marcando que esta mal y que debo usar otra cosa.
Como crees que deba hacer mi consulta?

Comment: Ocurre que tu sentencia de inserción es válida en un motor de base de datos como SQL Server, pero inválida del lado del Oledb/db. Mi sugerencia 1) inserta todo en una temporal del servidor, y luego 2) Exporta la temporal a DBF. De hecho, tal vez sea mejor por que tengas algún método mas directo y rápido para exportar una tabla completa y no iterar fila a fila.

Comment: Bien. Ya el punto 1 ya esta hecho. El punto 2 no se como hacerlo siendo que la Api me devuelve una lista de objetos.y tengo que insertarlos de a uno.

Comment: Ah, creo que ahora "me cae la ficha"... A ver, se me ocurre que lo que podría intentar es que, justo antes de ejecutar la inserción, hagas el count, salves el valor en una variable, en función de este valor calcules `tipo` y `veces` y luego al insert le pasas simplemente estos valores. También revisa la query, por que me parece que las columnas de insert no "matchen" con las del select.

Comment: Gracias Patricio. Lo voy a revisar. Desde un primer momento lo pense asi, pero todo este rebusque  de subconsultas las pidio el Analista y desarrollador y el pobre junior trainne esta peleando con Stackoverflow y todas las AI alrededor del mundo